# Showing a VisX graph inside a Semantic-UI-React Modal causes problems with z-index

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, z-index, semantic-ui-react

I'm adding a VisX graph inside Semantic-UI-React Modal.

The graph by itself shows the tooltip, crosshair and series glyphs correctly:

[image]

But when it's in a modal, all those appear beneath the modal:

[image]

I can reconstruct the tooltip with a higher z-index in the component I supply for the `renderTooltip` property, but it's lacking the crosshair and series glyph:

[image]

As these elements are added to the DOM on hover, it's impossible *for me* to catch them int he devtools and see what styles they have and inherit.
Is there some way I can set their z-index or fix this in some other way?

```
    const Visx: FC = () => {
      return (
        <Modal open>
          <Modal.Content>
            <XYChart width={900} height={500} xScale={{ type: 'time' }} yScale={{ type: 'linear' }}>
              <Grid rows numTicks={maxCount + 1} />
              <Axis
                orientation="left"
                label="Play count"
                numTicks={maxCount + 1}
                tickFormat={(value) => {
                  return value;
                }}
              />
              <Axis orientation="bottom" label="Date" />
              <LineSeries dataKey="plays" data={data} {...accessors} />
              <Tooltip
                showHorizontalCrosshair
                showVerticalCrosshair
                snapTooltipToDatumX
                snapTooltipToDatumY
                showSeriesGlyphs
                showDatumGlyph
                renderTooltip={({ tooltipData }) => {
                  const datum = tooltipData.nearestDatum?.datum as DataPoint | null;
                  return (
                    <div>
                      {datum?.count || 'no'} plays on {moment(datum?.date).format('MMM D, YYYY')}
                    </div>
                  );
                }}
              />
            </XYChart>
          </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding this global CSS style:

```css
.visx-tooltip {
  z-index: 9999; /* or whatever height is appropriate */
}
```